# Elegant indexing up to end of vector/matrix

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, indexing

Is it possible in R to say - I want all indices from position `i` to the end of vector/matrix?
Say I want a submatrix from 3rd column onwards. I currently only know this way:

```
A = matrix(rep(1:8, each = 5), nrow = 5) # just generate some example matrix...

A[,3:ncol(A)] # get submatrix from 3rd column onwards
```

But do I really need to write `ncol(A)`? Isn't there any elegant way how to say "from the 3rd column onwards"? Something like `A[,3:]`? (or `A[,3:...]`)?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Sometimes it's easier to tell R what you **don't** want.  In other words, exclude columns from the matrix using negative indexing:

Here are two alternative ways that both produce the same results:

```
A[, -(1:2)]
A[, -seq_len(2)]
```

Results:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    3    4    5    6    7    8
[2,]    3    4    5    6    7    8
[3,]    3    4    5    6    7    8
[4,]    3    4    5    6    7    8
[5,]    3    4    5    6    7    8
```

---

But to answer your question as asked: Use `ncol` to find the number of columns.  (Similarly there is `nrow` to find the number of rows.)

```
A[, 3:ncol(A)]

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    3    4    5    6    7    8
[2,]    3    4    5    6    7    8
[3,]    3    4    5    6    7    8
[4,]    3    4    5    6    7    8
[5,]    3    4    5    6    7    8
```

Answer (score 20):

For rows (not columns as per your example) then `head()` and `tail()` could be utilised.

```
A <- matrix(rep(1:8, each = 5), nrow = 5)
tail(A, 3)
```

is almost the same as

```
A[3:dim(A)[1],]
```

(the rownames/indices printed are different is all).

Those work for vectors and data frames too:

```
> tail(1:10, 4)
[1]  7  8  9 10
> tail(data.frame(A = 1:5, B = 1:5), 3)
  A B
3 3 3
4 4 4
5 5 5
```

For the column versions, you could adapt `tail()`, but it is a bit trickier. I wonder if `NROW()` and `NCOL()` might be useful here, rather than `dim()`?:

```
> A[, 3:NCOL(A)]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    3    4    5    6    7    8
[2,]    3    4    5    6    7    8
[3,]    3    4    5    6    7    8
[4,]    3    4    5    6    7    8
[5,]    3    4    5    6    7    8
```

Or flip this on its head and instead of asking R for things, ask it to drop things instead. Here is a function that encapsulates this:

```
give <- function(x, i, dimen = 1L) {
    ind <- seq_len(i-1)
    if(isTRUE(all.equal(dimen, 1L))) { ## rows
        out <- x[-ind, ]
    } else if(isTRUE(all.equal(dimen, 2L))) { ## cols
        out <- x[, -ind]
    } else {
        stop("Only for 2d objects")
    }
    out
}

> give(A, 3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
[2,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
[3,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
> give(A, 3, dimen = 2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    3    4    5    6    7    8
[2,]    3    4    5    6    7    8
[3,]    3    4    5    6    7    8
[4,]    3    4    5    6    7    8
[5,]    3    4    5    6    7    8
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following instruction:

```
A[, 3:length(A[, 1])]
```

Comment: If you're going to be doing a lot of subsetting,  first create  `dima <- dim(A)` and then just referenceit, e.g.   ` A[,3:dima[1]]`

Comment: Your `length(A[, 1])` gives the number of _rows_, but you are indexing the columns. If you want to use this type of approach, it should instead be `3:length(A[1,])`

Answer (score 0):

A dplyr readable renewed approach for the same thing:

```
A %>% as_tibble() %>%
  select(-c(V1,V2))
  
A %>% as_tibble() %>%
  select(V3:ncol(A))
```