# R syntax for selecting all but two first rows

Tags: r, syntax, row

How do I select all but the first two rows from e.g. the mtcars dataset?

I know that I can write `no_mazda <- mtcars[3:32]`, which does work as long as I know the number of rows. But when I don't know the number of rows I need to write e.g. `no_mazda <- mtcars[3:nrow(mtcars)]` which of cause also works, but:

Does R provide a smarter syntax than an expression that includes `mtcars` twice?

Comment: I asked a similar question some time ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500644/elegant-indexing-up-to-end-of-vector-matrix

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I prefer using `tail` with negative values for `n`:

```
tail(mtcars,-2)
```

Comment: yeah, this the analogy UNIX's `head -n -2`, I like it too :) +1

Comment: This answer is easier to code and interpretable. It should be selected as the answer.

Answer (score 38):

Negative indices mean "skip":

```
mtcars[-(1:2)]
```

skips first 2 indices of **vector** `mtcars`. If you need to skip first 10, just use `mtcars[-(1:10)]`.

Note that you speak about "dataset" but the code you use is for vectors, so I also responded is if `mtcars` is a vector. If `mtcars` is a dataframe and you are selecting rows, you have to use trailing comma:

```
mtcars[-(1:2),]
```

Comment: I was thinking about data frame, but my fingers wrote "dataset". mtcars is a data frame. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you happen to be using a [`data.table`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki) (and why would anyone not use it, if you are using a data.frame anyway?) - then you can use the handy `.N` operator ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33102714/what-does-n-means-in-data-table-in-r)), which in essence contains the number of rows in your table.

Here's a working example:

```
# make sure you have data.table
install.packages("data.table")
library(data.table)

# load the mtcars data
data(mtcars)
# Make a data table out of the mtcars dataset
cars <- as.data.table(mtcars, keep.rownames = TRUE)

# Take all the rows from a given index (e.g. 5) to the end
> cars[5:.N]
                     rn  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
 1:   Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
 2:             Valiant 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
 3:          Duster 360 14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
 4:           Merc 240D 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2 

... (truncated)
```

Just swap that 5 for a 2 in order to get the OP's desired output.

This of course allows dynamic use for tables of varying lengths, without having to always use the `length()` function. For example, if you know that you always want take the last 5 rows of a table and remove the very last row - getting 4 rows as output - then you can do something like the following:

```
> cars[(.N-4):(.N-1)]    # note the expressions for slicing must be in parentheses
           rn  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt qsec vs am gear carb
1:   Lotus Europa 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.9  1  1    5    2
2: Ford Pantera L 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.5  0  1    5    4
3:   Ferrari Dino 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.5  0  1    5    6
4:  Maserati Bora 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.6  0  1    5    8
```

Or simply always get the last row:

```
cars[.N]
```

... which is just as nice and concise as Python's equivalent: `cars[-1]`

Comment: Wow. I never knew about that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `dplyr` answer to how to remove the first two rows of `mtcars`:

```
mtcars %>% slice(-1:-2)

NROW(mtcars) # 32
NROW(mtcars %>% slice(-1:-2)) # 30
```