# What does ".N" mean in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table `dt`:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(a=LETTERS[c(1,1:3)],b=4:7)

   a b
1: A 4
2: A 5
3: B 6
4: C 7
```

The result of `dt[, .N, by=a]` is

```
   a N
1: A 2
2: B 1
3: C 1
```

I know the `by=a` or `by="a"` means grouped by `a` column and the `N` column is the sum of duplicated times of `a`. However, I don't use `nrow()` but I get the result. The `.N` is not just the column name? I can't find the document by `??".N"` in R. I tried to use `.K`, but it doesn't work. What does `.N` means?

Comment: An explanation of `.N` is in `?data.table` documentation under Arguments->by

Comment: More info in this cheat sheet https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/img/blog/data+table+cheat+sheet.pdf

Comment: I got the point why I can't find the document about ".N" in RStudio, because the ".N" information is written in the pdf reference manual but not in html document. Thank digEmAll and Pierre Lafortune. The cheat sheet is interesting and helpful for me to improve my coding skill.

Comment: Though this is a noob question, would you like to write an answer, @digEmAll? Maybe it's helpful to the new hand like me to manipulate data.table.

Comment: Please read the *Introduction to data.table* vignette either from the [github project page](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) or from [CRAN's data.table page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Think of `.N` as a variable for the number of instances. For example:

```
dt <- data.table(a = LETTERS[c(1,1:3)], b = 4:7)

dt[.N] # returns the last row
#    a b
# 1: C 7
```

Your example returns a new variable with the number of rows per case:

```
dt[, new_var := .N, by = a]
dt
#    a b new_var
# 1: A 4       2 # 2 'A's
# 2: A 5       2
# 3: B 6       1 # 1 'B'
# 4: C 7       1 # 1 'C'
```

For a list of all special symbols of data.table, see also https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.10.0/topics/special-symbols