# Create sequence of repeated values, with length based on a vector

Tags: r, dplyr, sequence, rep

How can I populate column ‘Night’ with a sequence of numbers, each repeating 3 times, and with the sequence restarting based on column ‘Site’? I’ve created a table showing what I want to achieve. This is a simplified version of my issue, I need to be able to use the code on a much larger dataframe.

[Image of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpuYJ.png)

| Site_date_time | Site | Night |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1_01012023_2200 | 1 | 1 |
| 1_01012023_2300 | 1 | 1 |
| 1_02012023_0000 | 1 | 1 |
| 1_02012023_2200 | 1 | 2 |
| 1_02012023_2300 | 1 | 2 |
| 1_03012023_0000 | 1 | 2 |
| 2_01012023_2100 | 2 | 1 |
| 2_01012023_2200 | 2 | 1 |
| 2_01012023_2300 | 2 | 1 |
| 2_02012023_2200 | 2 | 2 |
| 2_02012023_2300 | 2 | 2 |
| 2_03012023_0000 | 2 | 2 |
| 2_03012023_2200 | 2 | 3 |
| 2_03012023_2300 | 2 | 3 |
| 2_04012023_0000 | 2 | 3 |

```
#Code to create basic data frame of Site
site <- c(rep(1,times=6), rep(2,times=9))
df <- data.frame(site)
```

My main issue is the length of the sequence of numbers before restarting the sequence varies (i.e. the number of records for each site varies).
I could use the following if the number of rows for a given site was the same.

```
library("dplyr")
library("data.table")

# Create data frame of the site vector, with the number of observations per site of equal length
site <- c(rep(1,times=6), rep(2,times=6))
df <- data.frame(site)
# Create sequence with repeated numbers 
group_by(df,site) %>% mutate(night = rep(c(1:3), each=3))
```

But I need a function that allows me to create a sequence with repeated numbers based on the length of my grouped vector, rather than a defined length. I've tried to find a way of combining rep() with seq_along() or rowid(), but have had no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `length.out` argument of `rep()`. From the [docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rep.html):

> `length.out`: non-negative integer. The desired length of the output vector. Other inputs will be coerced to a double vector and the first element taken. Ignored if NA or invalid.

The length of your grouped vector can be calculated with [`dplyr::n()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/n).

```r
library(dplyr)

df |>
    mutate(night = rep(seq_len(n()), each = 3, length.out = n()), .by = site)
#    site night
# 1     1     1
# 2     1     1
# 3     1     1
# 4     1     2
# 5     1     2
# 6     1     2
# 7     2     1
# 8     2     1
# 9     2     1
# 10    2     2
# 11    2     2
# 12    2     2
# 13    2     3
# 14    2     3
# 15    2     3
```

Also, as you included `library(data.table)` in your question, if `df` is a `data.table` you can use the same approach with the `data.table` syntax, using [`.N`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33102714/what-does-n-mean-in-data-table) rather than `n()`:

```r
df[, night := rep(seq_len(.N), each = 3, length.out = .N), site]
```

Comment: This doesn't give the correct output for `.N > 9`. For example, with `df <- data.table(site = rep(1:2, c(6, 12)))`, it starts back at `1` before the `site = 2` sequence is done. `rep(1:.N, each...` should work.

Comment: @jblood94 I thought from the code in the question that the numbering was supposed to restart, but having had another look at the text, I think you're right. I have updated, thanks. (Note: I generally prefer `seq_len(x)` rather than `1:x` because of surprising behaviour when `x` is 0. Here that can't happen, or there would be no group, but I'm sticking with it anyway as it's a useful heuristic which stops me having to think too much about edge cases.)

Comment: Thank you @SamR and @jblood94! I'm pretty new to using R and spent most of a day trying to nut this out. Massively appreciate the help!